Fast question about -S option of ex
On Solaris 10
ex -h
ex: illegal option -- h
Usage: ex [- | -s] [-l] [-L] [-wn] [-R] [-S] [-r [file]] [-t tag]
[-v] [-V] [-x] [-C] [+cmd | -c cmd] file...

I see a "-S" option what does it mean? On old BSD mean "restricted mode"
On manpage is not documented.
I have tried to open a file with the "restricted mode" and it accept output from external commands (so is not restricted).

The ex editor is closely related to the vi editor (it's "the same editor", but vi is the "visual mode" and ex is the "line mode" variant).
Therefore, it may be relevant to look to the manual for the vi editor to try to figure out what the -S option does.
The following is from the official vi documentation from Oracle:

-S
This option is used in conjunction with the -t tag option to tell vi that the tags file can not be sorted and that, if the binary search
(which relies on a sorted tags file) for tag fails to find it, the
much slower linear search should also be done. Since the linear search
is slow, users of large tags files should ensure that the tags files
are sorted rather than use this flag. Creation of tags files normally
produces sorted tags files. See ctags(1) for more information on tags
files.


-t tag
Edits the file containing tag and position the editor at its definition. It is an error to specify more than one -t option.

So the -S option appears to be related to using tags in the vi and ex editors.  Tags are created with ctags and provide a developer with a way of quickly jumping to function declarations etc., in the project they are working on.  The -S option specifically tells the editor that the usual binary search algorithm for looking up tags can't be used, because the tag file isn't sortable (for whatever reason).
